# Hyperlink a HTML file inside another HTML file

Tags: html

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to HTML, but I would like to hyperlink a word to open another html file. I have an understanding of linking to another website, just not to another file on my computer. Can someone help? Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

suppose your file directory looks like this:

```
-- index.html
|
-- Some_folder
       |
       -- file1.html
       |
       -- file2.html
```

try this:

```
<a href="path/to/file">word</a>
```

for using the above mentioned directory from `index.html`:

```
<a href="Some_folder/file2.html">word</a>
```